# Should I use f:event or action element in PrettyFaces?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, prettyfaces

At the moment I am using the following code:

```
public void init() {
    question = questionBean.findQuestion(questionParamId);
}
```

Which is invoked by this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{questionShowBackingBean.questionParamId}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{questionShowBackingBean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

So the URL is: http://www.mycompany.com/show.xhtml?id=8

Now I have begun using PrettyFaces and I have seen the `<action>` element in the URL-mapping element I wonder if I could have written `<action>#{questionShowBackingBean.init}</action>` instead?

If so should I remove metadata element then, or should I use that instead because it may in the future change from using PrettyFaces? Last, where does the invocation in the `action` element occur? Does it occur before the listener I have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:event>` and `<action>` tags seem very similar, but have a few large differences that might influence your decision:

1. `<action>` allows you to perform navigation by returning a navigation string.
2. `<f:event>` is native JSF and lets you stay portable if you want to switch URL-rewriting tools in the future.
3. `<action>` lets you choose which phase to invoke the action via the `<action phaseId="..." />` attribute. `<f:event>` usually always invokes at the same time during RENDER_RESPONSE, after you really need it to invoke if you are using this information in JSF action method or in the INVOKE_APPLICATION phase.

By default, `<action>`s are invoked after the RESTORE_VIEW phase, but as I said before, you can control this yourself.

Usually I prefer to use `<action>` because it works without the need for any `<f:viewParam>` elements, and it also lets me navigate before any lifecycle processing has occurred (keeping things a bit more secure).

Comment: How would you bind the path parameters then? Setting them directly on the bean? Or can you pass them as argument to the action method?

Comment: I would bind the path parameters by using PrettyFaces injection, as you suggested.